# Free energy as a function of temperature over phase transition in molecular dynamics simulation

Tags: energy, computational-physics, phase-transition, simulations, molecular-dynamics

I've constructed a low density standard MD simulation (in Python), using the Lennard-Jones potential with an Andersen thermostat, of 10 particles in a box V = 10 $\times$ 10 $ \times$ 10 in the NVT ensemble. I'm looking to calculate the Helmholtz free energy (up to an additive constant) as a function of temperature over the phase transition from the particles clumping together in a small droplet through the melting of this cluster, i.e. $\Delta A$.

I know sampling in a situation like this is hard because of the large barriers involved, hence I'll do parallell tempering to sample effectively. However, the issue is I'm unsure of how to *actually* calculate the free energy. My method as it stands currently is to use what I've found as temperature integration:

\begin{equation}
  \frac{\Delta A}{\Delta T} = \frac{A(T_b)}{T_b} - \frac{A(T_a)}{T_a} = \int_{1/T_a}^{1/T_b} \langle H \rangle \ d(1/T),
\end{equation}
by $A = -k_b T \ln(Q)$, where Q is the partition function and then: $\frac{\partial A}{\partial (1/T)} = \langle H \rangle$. Based on this, what I'll do is sample $\langle H \rangle$, i.e. the average energy from the parallell tempering over a range of temperatures containing the transition and then integrate.

Is this a reasonable approach or am I missing something?

I found in [another question asked](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/are-there-any-md-packages-that-do-proper-free-energy-sampling-in-the-npt-ensembl), that the $\Delta A $ could be found by sampling the potential energy $U$ instead (as is done in GROMACS) per: $\Delta A = -k_b T \ln( \langle e^{- \beta \Delta U} \rangle)$ and this does seem reasonable, but how do I then construct the $\Delta A$ for the intermediate values so that I get the continuous curve between the two endpoints? I guess I could calculate $\Delta A$ for several points up to my final temperature $T$ using the average potential energy from the parallell tempering sampling, then I suppose these two methods would be quite similar.

A lot of what I've read otherwise employ thermodynamic integration using a parameter $\lambda$ smoothly varying between the two final states. But, using that approach I'm unsure of what to introduce as my $\lambda$. I was thinking of using perhaps the averaged separation distance between my particles, and then the $\lambda=0$ case would be in where the particles are bound in the droplet form and $\lambda = 1$ the unbound or melted form.

Comment: Matter Modeling is a better place perhaps?